# Code reads integer as float

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, recursion, integer

My code is reading iMid as a float and giving a TypeError, even after wrapping it in the integer function. Also, is there another way to find the index of the middle value, that is easier than what I have tried here?

```
def isIn(char, aStr):
'''
char: a single character
aStr: an alphabetized string

returns: True if char is in aStr; False otherwise
'''
# Your code here
import numpy as np
def iMid(x):
    '''
    x : a string

    returns: index of the middle value of the string

    '''

    if len(x) % 2 == 0:
        return int(np.mean(len(x)/2, (len(x)+2)/2)) #wrapped the 
                                                    # answer for iMid 
                                                    #in the integer function
    else:
        return int((len(x)+1)/2)

if char == aStr[iMid] or char == aStr: #iMid is not being interpreted as an integer
    return True
elif char < aStr[iMid]:
    return isIn(char, aStr[0:aStr[iMid]]) 
else:
    return isIn(char, aStr[aStr[iMid]:])

print(isIn('c', "abcd"))
```

Comment: `aStr[iMid]` is using the function `iMid` as an index. You want to call the function. `iMid(some_x_value)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In

```
if char == aStr[iMid] or char == aStr: #iMid is not being interpreted as an integer
```

`iMid` is not an integer. It's the function.

You need to call the function to get the integer it returns.

```
if char == aStr[iMid(aStr)] or char == aStr: #iMid is called and returns an integer
```

Comment: Thanks! I fixed this, but the problem is, the code works if the string is of 5 length but not for even numbers or numbers greater than 5. Can't figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

As doctorlove said, aStr[iMid] is using the function iMid as an index. Because iMid is a function object.
I think you should replace all aStr[iMid] with aStr[iMid(aStr)]

Answer (score 0):

Your issues is the way you are using the axis option in the numpy mean function.
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.mean.html

As a rule of thumb, 1 - the axis should be an integer, and 2 - of if a tuple it should within the dimensions of your array.

For instance, for array like this: [1,2], you have only 0 as for axis. if you have [[1,2]], then you can have 0 or 1 for the axis.